# Azure ‘Profiles - List By Resource Group’ rest api return {"value":[]}

Tags: azure, rest, cdn

I want to get the list of profiles under the resourcegroup with [azure rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cdn/profiles/list-by-resource-group?tabs=HTTP)

I can get the correct response by the 'try it' on the page:

[image: the screenshot]

But when I request it by code with the same params, I only get '{"value":[]}'. the code is:

```
string url = $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles?api-version=2023-05-01";
using HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
try
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseBody;
    }
    else
    {
        string errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        _logger.Info("Request failed: {0}, {1}", response.StatusCode, errorContent);
        return "";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.Error($"{ex.Message}: {ex.StackTrace}");
    return "";
}
```

Who know how to resolve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the REST API call from **`Try it`** page, the query works based on **signed-in**(delegated) user roles.

[image]

I got below **response** when I ran the REST API query from **`Try it`** page:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles?api-version=2023-05-01
```

[image]

To get the **same results** by running the request in code, I created one application and assigned **Reader** role under subscription like this:

[image]

When I ran below modified code with same parameters from `Try it` page, it generated token as a service principal and returned **same** **API response** as below:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        // Create the confidential client application object
        IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("appId")
            .WithClientSecret("secret")
            .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId"))
            .Build();

        // Get the access token
        string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" };
        AuthenticationResult authResult = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

        // Print the access token
        Console.WriteLine("Access token: {0}\n", authResult.AccessToken);

        // Call Management API using the access token
        await CallManagementApi(authResult.AccessToken);
    }

    static async Task CallManagementApi(string accessToken)
    {
        try
        {           
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var subscriptionId = "subId";
                var resourceGroupName = "rgname"; // Replace with resource group name
                var endpointUrl = $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles?api-version=2023-05-01";

                // Set the required headers
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(endpointUrl);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                // Process the API response as needed
                Console.WriteLine("\nAPI Response:\n" + result);
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            // Handle or log the exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error calling API: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, check how you generated the **access token** in your code with proper RBAC roles or not and make sure to pass **same values** for *subscription Id* and *resource group* parameters from `Try it` page.

Comment: When I use the token in the 'try it', the code gets the correct response. Thanks